# How to get return value from stored procedure with dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

The problem is to display all the table name from database having more than 10 rows and columns.

I have a cursor which is successfully returning table names with more than 10 columns, but when I try to count all the rows of particular table by passing table name as variable, I get an error like can not pass object as variable thus trying to get return value (all row count) using stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

I want to get return result as all row count from stored procedure thus
I can pass it to another variable into cursor.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @COUNTROW INT
DECLARE @COLUMNCOUNT INT
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT

DECLARE TABLECURSOR CURSOR SCROLL FOR 
    SELECT NAME FROM SYS.TABLES 

OPEN TABLECURSOR 
FETCH NEXT FROM TABLECURSOR INTO @TABLENAME 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --EXEC @COUNTROW = USP_XX_EXECUTESQL @TABLENAME     --[ CALL SP AND RETURN RESULT TO @COUNTROW ] 
        
    SELECT @COLUMNCOUNT = COUNT(*) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME 
        
    IF (@COLUMNCOUNT > 10)
    BEGIN
        PRINT @TABLENAME
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM TABLECURSOR INTO @TABLENAME 
END

CLOSE TABLECURSOR
DEALLOCATE TABLECURSOR


----STORED PROCEDURE TO COUNT ROWS 

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_XX_EXECUTESQL(@TABLE VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TABLE)     -- How to return value from here 
END
```

Comment: Read about stored procedures and parameters at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/parameters?view=sql-server-ver15, your procedure needs something to return to the caller. Being dynamic it needs an output parameter. And for dynamic SQL and its difficulties please read up on https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: It is time to start **seriously thinking** about the code you do write. A table name simply CANNOT contain 2 GB of characters. Use the sysname datatype for that. Your procedure also returns a resultset - the code using it retrieves the return value. That is another reason to avoid re-inventing the wheel. Simple searching on "count rows in all tables" will find many examples that you can adapt for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a cursor for this anyway, you could generate the SQL and execute it in one shot dynamically.

**But in any case, it's far better to just query the system views for rowcounts**

```sql
SELECT
  SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id),
  TableName = t.name,
  TotalRowCount = (
      SELECT SUM(p.rows)
      FROM sys.partitions p
      WHERE t.object_id = p.object_id
        AND p.index_id IN ( 0, 1 )  -- heap or clustered
  ),
  TotalColumns = (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM sys.columns c
      WHERE t.object_id = c.object_id
  )
FROM sys.tables t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer

```
   DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE  @params nvarchar(4000)
         
    SET @TABLE = N'AGENT'
    SELECT @sql = N'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) 
                    FROM  ' + @TABLE 
    
       SELECT @params = N'   @cnt int OUTPUT'
                     
                   
    
    DECLARE @cnt  int`enter code here`
    EXEC sp_executesql  @sql,  @cnt OUTPUT
    SELECT @cnt  AS TOTALROW
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).